# How to set Boolean metadata using UpdateListItems?

Tags: web-services

I am trying to use the UpdateListItems Web Service API call to create a new (customised) folder and set meta data at the same time. Here is my batch element:

```
    <Batch ListVersion="1" OnError="Continue" xmlns="">
       <Method Cmd="New" ID="1">
          <Field Name="ID">New</Field>
          <Field Name="FSObjType">1</Field>
          <Field Name="BaseName">Students A/AHN (AHCJD1001)</Field>
          <Field Name="ContentType">Student Folder</Field>
          <Field Name="StudentID">AHCJD1001</Field>
          <Field Name="Surname">AHN</Field>
          <Field Name="Status_x0020_Code">C</Field>
          <Field Name="Archived">1</Field>
       </Method>
    </Batch>
```

Now, it all works perfectly - EXCEPT the Archived field.  That is a boolean field in SharePoint and nothing I do in this batch allows me to ever set it to true.  All the other fields work fine, setting surname, student ID, content type and status code.  I have tried using 1 and True as Archived values, neither works.  It always ends up as "No" in SharePoint.

Any ideas?

Chris

Comment: Have you tried setting the value as "Yes"?

Comment: Good idea.  Tried with "Yes", "TRUE" and "True" - none work.  All still leave Archived showing as "No" when using View Properties.

Comment: I have now discovered several other blog posts that imply it's supposed to just be '1': http://hemsoft.blogspot.com/2010/04/updating-listdocument-librarys-checkbox.html and http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/69/10096994/add-calendar-item-thru-web-service-in-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: Are you sure the field is Boolean? I have a vague memory of similar problem and I think the field ended up being some other type.

Comment: Site Settings says it's a "Yes/No (check box)" column.

Comment: May sound strange, but have you tried using a 0 or -1 to see if anything changes.

Answer (score 2):

I got really curious what the diagnosis is.
I've double checked and for me such Batch works:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<Batch xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" OnError=\"Return\">
    <Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"New\">
        <Field Name=\"Title\">Test</Field>
        <Field Name=\"ID\">New</Field>
        <Field Name=\"Done\">TRUE</Field>
    </Method>
</Batch>
```

Works with "TRUE" and "True".

And what do you get in xml returned from UpdateListItems? 
Mine (check ows_Done for the boolean column):

```
<Result ID="1,New"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<ErrorCode>0x00000000&lt;/ErrorCode>&lt;ID />
<z:row
ows_ContentTypeId="0x0100C27C8A4A9DD66247971ECA37E457EF11"
ows_Title="Test"
...
ows_ID="39"
ows_Done="1"
```

So I've checked with

```
<Field Name=\"Done\">1</Field>
```

and it works as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

I recheck this issue and it works fine with my code snippet. What I did is, added one column Archived of type (Yes/No (check box)).

Take one boolean variable inside your code.

```
bool IsArchived = true;


<Batch ListVersion="1" OnError="Continue" xmlns="">
       <Method Cmd="New" ID="1">
          <Field Name="ID">New</Field>
          <Field Name="FSObjType">1</Field>
          <Field Name="BaseName">Students A/AHN (AHCJD1001)</Field>
          <Field Name="ContentType">Student Folder</Field>
          <Field Name="StudentID">AHCJD1001</Field>
          <Field Name="Surname">AHN</Field>
          <Field Name="Status_x0020_Code">C</Field>
          <Field Name="Archived">IsArchived</Field>
       </Method>
    </Batch>
```

This is what i did and it worked as expected.

Comment: What do you mean "Take one boolean variable inside your code."?

Comment: I had certain requirement to update field value using SharePoint web services. You can set your boolean variable and pass that value as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about this [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2010/05/05/content-query-web-part-and-the-yes-no-field.aspx). The blog entry talks about the Content Query Web Part and does not use Web Services but I think in principle the issue is the same. Bottom line, use "1" for Yes and "0" for No.